# Is getElementById or getElementsByClassName[0] faster?

Tags: javascript, html, performance

Is it faster to use getElementById

```
document.getElementById('foo').style.visibility = 'visible';
```

or getElementByClassName[0]

```
document.getElementsByClassName('foo')[0].style.visibility = 'visible';
```

I have read that too many IDs can hamper performance, which is why I am trying to shy away from IDs. But if it is faster to use an ID for a quick JavaScript lookup, I will gladly do so.

Comment: Depends entirely on the page (and likely the browser). Have you actually determined this is a useful optimization to make?

Comment: @Dave Newton Not necessarily, I just read an article which explains how every ID creates a new property, and therefore inhibits performance. There were other reasons why not to use IDs as well: https://dev.to/clairecodes/reasons-not-to-use-ids-in-css-4ni4

Comment: The article is for CSS performance, yet you are asking about javascript...

Comment: @vanowm Ideally, I would like to have the best performance possible. This would include both CSS and JavaScript. However, I care more for JavaScript performance, which is why I am asking this question.

Comment: @Polar I don't know what you mean by the first part, and the linked article has nothing to do with performance.

Comment: @Dave Newton I was saying that I have not determined this would be a useful optimization to make, but I read a comment on the article which suggests IDs can make things slower. But it seems that I did not research well enough before asking, and now is apparent that the performance gains are minimal. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getElementById` would be the fastest method, since it's simple table lookup.

`getElementsByClassName` the same as `querySelector` almost [twice as slow](https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/1144/1/getelementbyid-vs-queryselector-vs-getelementsbyclassna).

For best performance use ids for javascript and classes for CSS.